# Endless update the state when implementing infinite scrolling in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want add infinity scrolling to my project, but is faced with problem. I get error in console, what the my sate is update very often. I use plugin:  React Infinite Scroller. if I understand correctly, when open page, must show one page and make request to the 'gen_div' func but error occurs. Thanks!

```
MyComponent {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {div_list: []}
    }

    gen_div() {
       var new_list = this.state.div_list;
       new_list.push(<div>1</div>);
       new_list.push(<div>2</div>);
       new_list.push(<div>3</div>);
       this.setState({div_list: new_list})
    }

    render() {
       return(
           <InfiniteScroll
             pageStart={1}
             loadMore={this.gen_div}
             hasMore={true}
             loader=(<h4>Loading..</h4>)
            >
              {this.state.div_list}
            </InfiniteScroll>
       )
    }

}
```

Comment: There are a lot of things that may be an issue. For example, ```this`` binding looks to be incorrect in the above example. Can you please edit to share the exact error?

Comment: You're mutating the state btw. `var new_list = this.state.div_list` creates a reference to the state array, and then `.push()` is mutating the state array. Mutating state in React is a big no-no. Make a duplicate of state arrays/objects you want to change: `var new_list = this.state.div_list.slice();`. Have a look into the spread operator too, allows making copies of arrays/objects short and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) with a callback.

```
gen_div = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        let new_list = prevState.div_list;
        new_list.push(<div>1</div>);
        new_list.push(<div>2</div>);
        new_list.push(<div>3</div>);
        return({{...prevState}, {div_list: new_list}});
    }
}
```